# If I travel to the UK while living abroad, can I keep my Permanent Residence valid?

Tags: visas, uk, new-zealand

I'll be making a move to Auckland, New Zealand soon.

I am a UK Permanent Resident holder.

I understand that if you are away from the UK for 2 years or longer then you lose your 'Indefinite Leave to Remain' and then have to apply for a 'Returning Resident' Visa (how would I qualify for this?).

If I return to the UK for a week and then return to New Zealand within the 2 year time-period, do I get 2 more years?

Also, for context, I have been living in the UK for >13 years. 
I have grown up in the UK from the ages of 12 - 26. 
A lot of my closest friends live here but none of my family.

Comment: Have you read through [Apply for a Returning Resident visa](https://www.gov.uk/returning-resident-visa)? That answers a lot of your questions.

Comment: The 2 years does not 'reset' every time you enter the UK.  You might be able to qualify for the RR visa if you want to recover your ILR, but for your question, it's a no. Please use Expats.  http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions